# Objective-c modeling class advice needed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need some advice on modeling model objects in Objective-c, most of my background is in database world (more than 20 years) so sometimes is difficult to me to wrap my mind around the objective-c way of modeling classes.

I have three classes like that:

**EventTemplate:**

```
amount
concept
createdAt
dayOfMonth
isActive
periodicity
repeatEvery
typeOfTransaction
updatedAt
```

**EventOccurrence:**

```
amount 
concept 
createdAt 
eventType 
isActive 
scheduledDate 
updatedAt
```

And the last one **Timeline**, the modeling of which is the object of my question. Timeline class is supposed to hold instances of EventOccurence, I've tried to implement it like this:

**TimeLine:**

```
NSMutableArray* eventOccurrences;

//CRUD methods
- AddEventOcurrence
- RemoveEventOcurrence
- UpdateEventOcurrence
```

Most of the code I've seen takes this approach, but this lend to some ugly syntax like:

```
timeline.eventOccurences[0].amount instead of timeline[0].amount
```

How to avoid it and get the second syntax?, any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against your CRUD statements. Since you've got an `NSMutableArray`, you can just manipulate it directly with new/updated `EventOccurence` instances (or delete, as needed). Basically, `NSMutableArray` comes with CRUD capabilities, which you are probably just basically wrapping with your own. That's an extra layer that's probably unnecessary.

If `timeline` is just a wrapper around an `NSMutableArray` of `EventOccurence` objects, why not just make `timeline` an `NSMutableArray` property of a class? Maybe an app-level singleton object or something.

If you did that (we'll go with `AppDelegate` for now, though I don't recommend it), you could use the following code:

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
EventOccurence *firstEvent = del.timeline[0];
firstEvent.amount = ...
```

Does that help you out?

Comment: The singleton path is something I've been thinking about, but as it really have a very bad reputation(some posts talks about singletons as evil) I discarded it. So wrapping up: in Objective C you don't usually implement your own collections (aka indexes, iterators, etc.) you use the supplied ones and avoid adding a new layer. What todo if I want to hide the array from callers of this class?

Comment: Singletons aren't evil; you just need to make sure to use them wisely. Objective-C has a wealth of rich, built-in collections, so implementing your own is frequently at least unnecessary, if not counter-productive. If you need to hide from callers, you have the ability to implement a private interface in your implementation file and simply expose your public interface in your header. Bear in mind, however, that Objective-C allows callers to call any method, so if they know about it, you marking it "private" doesn't actually stop anything.

Answer (score 1):

> timeline.eventOccurences[0].amount

This means that you have one `timeline`, it has an array of `eventOccurences`, you want to get the first on and return its `amount`

> timeline[0].amount

This means you have an array of `timeline`, you want to get the first one are return the `amount`

Neither of these use your CRUD methods. And they mean very different things. You need to decide on your structure, and what methods you want to add to your classes that can 'drill down' through your data structure to provide collated results. For instance, you could have:

```
timeline.amount
```

return the *total* `amount` summed across all `eventOccurences`. You would add a method for this yourself...

Comment: OK the CRUD methods are the public API. When I said timeline.eventOcurrences[0].amount is the internal calls inside the class. Sorry for not stating it clearly.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have the `timeline` as part of the call as you have direct access to the `eventOccurences` array. So you would just have `eventOccurences[0].amount`